# combining ccze and grep?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe

`ccze` is an excellent log colorizer. The problem is, that despite what is says in manual, there are no plugins in `/usr/lib64/ccze` or `$HOME/.ccze`. It looks like all the plugins are compiled into the binary (so they are not a plugins really) and I can't modify highlighting easy.

**What I want to achieve?**

I need to add some more patterns to be highlighted in red. Especially a single `0` surrounded by white spaces. Since I can't easily modify `ccze` I was thinking about combining it with grep:

```
tail -f `/bin/ls -1td /var/log/updates/index_*.log` | ccze -A | grep --color '\| 0 '
```

But this doesn't produce any output (hangs?) despite the fact that:

```
tail -f `/bin/ls -1td /var/log/updates/index_*.log` | grep --color '\| 0 '
```

Correctly highlights zeros and:

```
tail -f `/bin/ls -1td /var/log/updates/index_*.log` | ccze -A
```

Correctly highlights the rest.

**Time for question**

Can you please help me modify the command above so `ccze` and `grep` play nicely together? Or just how to customize `ccze` - **without recompiling**, so it correctly highlights new stuff.

**Answers I don't want to see**

- Why don't you use multitail, it's so perfect?
- Why don't you use any other library (which is not a drop-in replacement for `ccze`)?

Comment: "*this doesn't work*" isn't a useful description of the problem. Precisely, what does `tail | ccze -A | grep` do? Hang? Produce an error message? Overheat your CPU?

Comment: @Robᵩ - yes it hangs and doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ccze` FAQ](https://github.com/cornet/ccze/blob/master/FAQ) mentions the reason that, on some systems, the "plugins" are actually "built-in": there is a PCRE compilation error that the author doesn't know how to fix other than statically linking the plugins.

So, you're dead in the water modifying how the plugins work, which leaves *in situ* modification. But... the problem with *in situ* modification is that, in general, [it's not possible to detect the current color, set a new one, then get back to that current color](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177341/50240).

Consider:

```
ccze -A <httpd.log | sed "s/ 0 /$(tput setaf 2)&$(tput sgr0)/"
```

Except that this resets the colors following the match to normal terminal, which may corrupt the colored output you want. Therefore, you might want to set and reset something other than color, like **bold**, *blink*, or *underline*.

Consider:

```
ccze -A <httpd.log | sed "s/ 0 /$(tput smso)&$(tput rmso)/"
```

Which brings that " 0 " into bold. I'm using `tput` here for convenience, you can of course use direct [ANSI escape sequences](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/ansi_escapes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Reading manual it looks like you can use

```
-c, --color KEY=COLOR
    Set the color of the keyword KEY to COLOR, like one would do in one of the configuration files.
```

You might want to try to set 0 as the KEY.

**UPDATE:**

Please ignore the above.

I figured out what is happening. First of all this doesn't hang. It's because you are using

```
tail -f
```

When you remove **-f** then it will exit quickly with grep returning nothing. The second thing is why with you see this behavior. That's because ccze is formatting the output with the ANSI color codes. You can test it with tee e.g.:

```
tail `/bin/ls -1td /var/log/updates/index_*.log` | ccze -A | tee my_log
```

When you open **my_log** you will find a lot of ANSI codes e.g. my file contains:

```
| 0 Some message
```

However, that's the **ccze -A** log using **tee**:

```
^[[22m^[[36m|^[[0m^[[22m^[[36m ^[[0m^[[22m^[[37m0^[[0m^[[22m^[[36m ^[[0m^[[22m^[[36mSome^[[0m^[[22m^[[36m ^[[0m^[[22m^[[36mmessage^[[0m^[[22m^[[36m ^[[0m^[[0m
```

As you can see, there is no longer **| 0** string. That's why grep returns nothing. If you don't want to reinstall ccze then I don't see the clean solution but using this weird pattern in your grep command.

**UPDATE 2:**

You can try also with sed:

```
tail `/bin/ls -1td /var/log/updates/index_*.log` | sed -e 's/| 0/\x1b[31m&\x1b[39m/' | ccze -A
```

But in my case **ccze** changed the color of **0**.

There is also a config file in:

```
/etc/cczerc
```

You can change the color of numbers etc.

Comment: The `KEY` is a keyword - a predefined set of words/phrases defined separately for each profile. You can't change it. This setting is helpful for example when you want to change the color of the date string from default to something else.